# Showing rows that don't satisfy a relationship: is this correct, or is there an easier way?

Tags: t-sql, join

For one of our customers, I had to turn on an ASP.NET role for everyone that didn't have that role. My current query (which works) is as follows, but I'm having the idea that this query can be made easier / simpler and that I took a roundabout way.

The ASP.NET membership model is as follows: aspnet_Users with a many-to-many to aspnet_Roles. That many-to-many relationship is stored in aspnet_UsersInRoles.

```
SELECT 
  u2.UserId,
  u2.UserName,
  r2.RoleId,
  r2.RoleName   
FROM .[dbo].[aspnet_Users] u2
CROSS JOIN .[dbo].[aspnet_Roles] r2
WHERE not exists (
  SELECT 
    r.[ApplicationId]
    ,r.[RoleId]
    ,r.[RoleName]
    ,ur.[UserId]
    ,u.UserName
  FROM .[dbo].[aspnet_Roles] r
  INNER JOIN .[dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles] ur on r.RoleId = ur.RoleId
  INNER JOIN .[dbo].[aspnet_Users] u on u.UserId = ur.UserId
  WHERE r.RoleId = '73635AD6-0282-4289-85C4-7B4359D1D640' and u.UserId = u2.UserId
) AND r2.RoleId = '73635AD6-0282-4289-85C4-7B4359D1D640'
```

So, basically, I first calculate the cross join of all users with that role, and then subtract everyone who already is in that role in order to get the resulting set of users who are *not* in that role.

It feels like a roundabout way of figuring this out. Is there an easier (or more intuitive) way to arrive at the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Sql Server 2005 or above;

```
;WITH cte AS (
 select u.userId from aspnet_Users u inner join aspnet_UsersInRoles ur
 on u.UserId = ur.UserId
 where ur.RoleId = '73635AD6-0282-4289-85C4-7B4359D1D640'
)
SELECT u.UserId,u.UserName,r.RoleId,r.RoleName 
FROM    aspnet_Users u INNER JOIN
        aspnet_UsersInRoles ur ON u.UserId = ur.UserId INNER JOIN
        aspnet_Roles r ON ur.RoleId = r.RoleId
WHERE u.UserId NOT IN (select UserId from cte)
```

Comment: That does make it a lot easier. First, you get everyone who is in that role, and then exclude them from the many-to-many. That was my initial idea, but I couldn't really get it to work.